# Copying an element's html content using Jquery to another element, not working for checkbox status (checked, unchecked) ?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

This is my simple html page :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script >
      function copy(){
         $("#two").html($("#one").html());
      }
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<button onclick="copy()">copy</button>

<div id="one">
<input type="checkbox" name="test" >
</div>

<div id="two">
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

when I click the button, contents of `div#one` is copied to `div#two`, but when I first click on checkbox (It is checked now!) and then click the Button, The second checkbox is produced, but it is not checked!! why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `.html()` only copies the plain HTML code of the target element, not other data like whether or not boxes are checked. If you want to include such data, use `.clone()` instead.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script >
      function copy(){
         $("#two").html($("#one").clone());
      }
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<button onclick="copy()">copy</button>

<div id="one">
<input type="checkbox" name="test" >
</div>

<div id="two">
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

This will work for any number of checkboxes, as well as data for other elements such as a textbox's value.

Comment: IMPORTANT!!!! Note that for all the answers saying to clone the element - one issue occurs - if you clone the div with id #one into the div with id of #two - then the entire #one div INCLUDING the id of that div will be inserted into #two. Therefore you will have two divs with id of #one. The #two will contain a div with id of #one inside it. So you need to update the id of the second one because each id must be unique.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use jQuery `.clone()` method, which will avoid the `.is(':checked')` verification. Instead of using `.html()` replace your code to below:

```
$('#two').html($("#one").clone());
```

**Alternate method:**

You can also first check and see if the first checkbox is checked using jQuery.

```
// verify if first checkbox is checked
if ($('#one input[type="checkbox"]').is(':checked')) {
   // add checked attribute to second checkbox
   $('#two input[type="checkbox"]').prop("checked", true);
}
```

Have a look at the code below.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script >
      function copy(){
         $('#two').html($("#one").clone());                
      }
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<button onclick="copy()">copy</button>

<div id="one">
<input type="checkbox" name="test" >
</div>

<div id="two">
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! its working. But I have several checkboxes , Do I have to do this for all?  why jquey can not copy `checked` attribute ?

Comment: Do I have to check the `checked` attr and manually add it myself?

Comment: @AhmadMobaraki check the revised answer. `.html()` only copies the render html, the selected or checked item is not passed over, but if you use `.clone()` it will copy the current item over.

Answer (score 1):

.html() do not copy all the elements with their attributes. So you just use this line -

```
$("#one").clone().appendTo("#two");
```